# Safari pauses CSS3 Animation on submission of a form or redirect

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I am developing a simple web page where I want to show a spinner in the center of the page when the form is submitted. It works in Chrome but, in Safari the CSS animation stops as soon as the form is submitted. Since the animation is 2 seconds longs it does not perform the animation at all.

This is the entire HTML, CSS and JS to replicate the issue. Save the contents in a HTML file and open it in Chrome first to see how it should behave and then open in Safari to see the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      .circular {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 60px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -30px;
        margin-top: -30px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;  
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        width: 60px;
      }
      .circle {
        animation: circular-indeterminate-bar-rotate 2s linear infinite;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .path {
        animation: circular-indeterminate-bar-dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
        fill: none;
        stroke: rgba(12,18,28, 0.87);
        stroke-dasharray: 1.25, 250;
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-miterlimit: 20;
        stroke-width: 4;
        transition: stroke-dasharray .35s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
      }

      @keyframes circular-indeterminate-bar-rotate {
        to {
          transform: rotate(1turn);
        }
      }

      @keyframes circular-indeterminate-bar-dash {
        0% {
          stroke-dasharray: 1.25, 250;
          stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        }

        50% {
          stroke-dasharray: 111.25, 250;
          stroke-dashoffset: -43.75;
        }

        to {
          stroke-dasharray: 111.25, 250;
          stroke-dashoffset: -155;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="circular">
      <svg class="circle" viewBox="0 0 60 60"><circle class="path" cx="30" cy="30" r="25"></circle></svg>
    </div>
    <script>
      window.location.href = 'http://httpbin.org/delay/100';
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add Vendor prefixes in css.

Comment: @MerajKhan I did but that does not help. You can try it yourself with the code I have up in my question.

Comment: Ah I see now, the dasharray animation stops, but the rotation one doesn't. Interesting, can't find why nor how to workaround. Your best bet? Raise an issue to Safari. `fill` property is also concerned, but not `transform` nor `filter`.

Comment: I think they messed up the `stroke[-XXX]` and `fill[-XXX]` properties. All these properties are affected. I can see there is a `strokeColor` property defined on the element's StyleDeclaration, even though it doesn't produce anything to set it... Maybe they try to parse `stroke` as a shorthand property while it's not. But then why does it break only when the page unloads... I've got no idea.

Answer (score -1):

This is working Fine in safari also.

```css
.circular {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 60px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -30px;
        margin-top: -30px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;  
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);  
            -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);  
                transform: rotate(-90deg);
        width: 60px;
      }
      .circle {
        -webkit-animation: circular-indeterminate-bar-rotate 2s linear infinite;
                animation: circular-indeterminate-bar-rotate 2s linear infinite;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .path {
        -webkit-animation: circular-indeterminate-bar-dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
                animation: circular-indeterminate-bar-dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
        fill: none;
        stroke: rgba(12,18,28, 0.87);
        stroke-dasharray: 1.25, 250;
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-miterlimit: 20;
        stroke-width: 4;
        -webkit-transition: stroke-dasharray .35s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
        -o-transition: stroke-dasharray .35s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
        transition: stroke-dasharray .35s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
      }

      @-webkit-keyframes circular-indeterminate-bar-rotate {
        to {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(1turn);
                  transform: rotate(1turn);
        }
      }

      @keyframes circular-indeterminate-bar-rotate {
        to {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(1turn);
                  transform: rotate(1turn);
        }
      }

      @-webkit-keyframes circular-indeterminate-bar-dash {
        0% {
          stroke-dasharray: 1.25, 250;
          stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        }

        50% {
          stroke-dasharray: 111.25, 250;
          stroke-dashoffset: -43.75;
        }

        to {
          stroke-dasharray: 111.25, 250;
          stroke-dashoffset: -155;
        }
      }

      @keyframes circular-indeterminate-bar-dash {
        0% {
          stroke-dasharray: 1.25, 250;
          stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        }

        50% {
          stroke-dasharray: 111.25, 250;
          stroke-dashoffset: -43.75;
        }

        to {
          stroke-dasharray: 111.25, 250;
          stroke-dashoffset: -155;
        }
      }
```

```html
 <div class="circular">
      <svg class="circle" viewBox="0 0 60 60"><circle class="path" cx="30" cy="30" r="25"></circle></svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: You probably didn't get the question. OP's problem is that the animation does stop when the page unloads (but actually even before it really did). They don't have a problem with the animation otherwise.